# AWS EC2 SSH Tunnel Bastion Server

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, ssh, ssh-tunnel

Trying to understand how this works, documentation isn't very clear.  Using AWS quickstart-mongo, I am making a VPN for 3 Mongo nodes, with a bastion server.  I can log into my bastion server via SSH and my key.  Then I can copy the key to bastion server and SSH into the primary replica node.  This node is running mongo and shows via rs.status() that all 3 nodes are running correctly.

Once logged into bastion server, I try to do `curl primary-mongo-node-ip:27017`, and it seems to hang.

Local Computer -> Bastion Server -> Replica Node 1 / 2 / 3

I think I understand I need to somehow connect to Bastion server, then set up a ssh forwarding to primary-mongo-node-ip:27017, sec1-mongo-node-ip:27017, sec2-mongo-node-ip:27017, so that my mongo URI connection looks like this:

SSH into bastion-dns
mongodb://user:pass@localhost:1000,localhost:1001,localhost:1002/database

How do I do this when I cant event connect to the server on bastion servers without SSH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the Mongo instances allow traffic from Bastion Host (in security groups) for required ports, you can use SSH tunnelling mechanism to access the cluster/instance from your local host:

```
ssh -N -L <local_port_x>:<mongoDB instance ip>:<mongo_port_y> <ssh_username>@<bastion_host_ip> -i <ssh_key_path>
```

`Local_Port_X` : Port on your local machine where you want to access remote Mongo instance

`MongoDB Instance IP` : ip address for ec2 instance hosting MongoDB

`Mongo_Port_Y` : Port that MongoDB is listening on (seems 27017 from your question - please do verify that you can talk to Mongo Instance from within Bastion host on this port)

`Bastion_Host_Ip` : IP address on bastion host which should directly be reachable from your local machine